# how to create pointer to 2nd dimension of 3 dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 3 dimensional array and want to create a pointer to the 2nd dimension.

```
uint32_t m0[4096][256][8];
uint32_t (*m1)[256][8] = &m0[0];
uint32_t *m2 = m1[2];      //<- warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

// do something with m2[0], m2[1].... m2[7]
```

Obviously there is something with the above code.  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m1[2]` is `*(m1+2)`.
Type of `*(m1+2)` is the same as the type of `*m1`, which is `unit32_t [256][8]`.

For that reason, the following line is wrong.

```
uint32_t* m2 = m1[2];
```

What you need to use is:

```
uint32_t* m2 = (*m1)[2];
```

Comment: fixed the line, made no difference, same error message

Comment: @poby, not sure why. It works for me on my desktop and online at https://ideone.com/pHYTZz.

Comment: This is weird!  It actually works only if the `m2[0] = 10;` line is included.  If I don't do an assignation, I get the above error.

Comment: @poby, the error is probably about an unused variable, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @R.Sahu, yeah you're right, I didn't notice the error was different.

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd dimension is not `uint32_t *` it's simply `m[n]`, or exactly as you've declared `m1`. `m1[n]` is `uint32_t[8]`

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because the second dimension's values aren't stored next to each other in memory.

Comment: From the accepted answer I take that @poby means a flattened array of the last two dimensions. My answer isn't relevant